# difference between "loop_until_bit_is_set" macro and while() expression

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc

this piece of code in running on ATmega2560, so what is the difference between these two:

```
while(UCSR0A & 0b00100000 == 0);  // check UDRE0 bit if it is 1
```

and:

```
loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
```

as you can see this is for UART transmission, but if i use the first one I could't get desired output on terminal, for example if i do `printf("Hello world\n");` the actual terminal display is: `HeHeHe......`. However the latter one works. You can find this piece of code in `stdio.h`.

Comment: Help stomp out pointless comments. `while(UCSR0A & _BV(UDRE0));`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams shouldn't that be `while(!(UCSR0A & _BV(UDRE0)));` ? As far as I understand, he wanted to loop *until* the bit is set, not *while* it's set...

Comment: @vaxquis: That would be an answer, not a rewrite of the code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

`==` has higher priority than `&`; also, no need to check for `== 0` - you should try

```
while(!(UCSR0A & 0b00100000));
```

or rather, using bit macro

```
while(!(UCSR0A & _BV(UDRE0)));
```

instead.

Comment: oh yeah you are right, thanks!! I wish I could vote, but not enough reputation...